# slang or metaphor : I saw a lion kiss a deer

Tags: slang, metaphors

I love the song "Lost Stars" from the movie "Begin Again"
and there are these sentences in the second part (paragraph):

> Who are we? Just a speck of dust within the galaxy?
>   Woe is me. if we're not careful turns into reality
>   Don't you dare let our best memories bring you sorrow
>   **Yesterday I saw a lion kiss a deer**
>   Turn the page maybe we'll find a brand new ending
>   Where we're dancing in our tears

What is the meaning of the expression "I saw a lion kiss a deer"? Is this a metaphor or slang?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.  Are you asking about the literal meaning of the line?  (It should be clear if you know what "lion", "kiss" and "deer" are.)  Are you asking if this is a common expression in English? (It isn't, but see Isaiah 11:6 in the Bible, which is a similar expression that is widely known.)  Are you asking what deeper meaning is intended by the line?  (As with any poetry, that's up to your own interpretation, and would not be on topic for this site.)

Comment: I've never seen a lion kiss a deer, but [a dog kissing a cat](http://www.google.com/search?q=dog+kiss+cat&tbm=isch) is easy to find on the web. ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for the reasons set out by @Nate

Comment: Hi @NateEldredge, I never read the Bible before, but you show me the way to find out the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A fabulous site called [Genius.com](http://genius.com) has a lot of annotated songs and such like. This one is, and I've [linked it here](http://genius.com/4177921/Adam-levine-lost-stars/Yesterday-i-saw-a-lion-kiss-a-deer-turn-the-page-maybe-well-find-a-brand-new-ending), and quoted the relevant parts. A screenshot is included to show the image:

> ‘I saw a lion kiss a deer’ is a remarkable thing to witness; predator and prey united in an ardent embrace. This is an contradictory statement because this seldom happens unless ‘kiss’ is used euphemistically.

[image]

Unsurprisingly, the image above is the only one I could find on a [Google Image search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=lion%20kiss%20a%20deer&site=imghp). This highlights exactly how rare it is.